# Get the album list of all the songs in an alphabetical order

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

here is the code I wrote and the error is that `getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.Album.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null)` has the error that Album cannot be resolved. Is this the correct way to get the album list or is there any other better way? I want to do the same for genre, artist so if there is a different way for them, please tell that too :

```
public class AlbumsFragment extends Fragment{
public AlbumsFragment() {}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_albums, container, false);
    ListView albumView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.albumsView);
    ArrayList<String> albumList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM};
    final Cursor albumCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.Album.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);

    if (albumCursor != null) {
        if (albumCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int albumIndex = albumCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                albumList.add(albumCursor.getString(albumIndex));
            } while (albumCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    albumCursor.close();
    return view;
            }
```

}

Comment: Please can you not downvote it and solve the problem instead? Better way to use your experienced and intelligent brains isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Code would be

You should query the Albums like this

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Albums._ID, Albums.ALBUM, Albums.ARTIST, Albums.ALBUM_ART, Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS };
String selection = null;
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder = Media.ALBUM + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

Comment: Its a fragment and I tried using the getActivity() method for contentResolver but it didnt work.

Comment: Please paste your Logcat.

Comment: It cannot find the symbol "contentResolver". Probably because I havent extended AppCompatActivity.because its a fragment. Any other way around it? There is no error other than that